# How to match text but don't match if the regex is empty?

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

The following function searches elements by `text`:

```js
function findElementsByText(selectors, text) {
  if (text === '') return []

  const regex = new RegExp(text)
  const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll(selectors)]

  return elements.filter((element) => {
    return element.textContent.match(regex)
  })
}

const selectors = 'a'
const text = ''
const foundElements = findElementsByText(selectors, text)
console.log(foundElements)
```

```html
<a></a>
<a>Text</a>
```

As you can see, I'm returning `[]` if `text` is empty. Without that line, the function will match all the `a` tags.

I wonder if there's a way to tell the regex: match `text` but don't match if the regex is empty. This way I can remove the if-statement. Or maybe having the if-statement is the best option?

Comment: For the above html, what response should return your function?

Comment: i think the if statement is the better option, a simple text compare is faster than evaluating a regex

Comment: I did not get it. If your function works correctly and you want to just shorten the code, then I would recommend using XPath instead of CSS Selector, it allows you to find elements by containing text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like that.

```
if (!text) return
const text;
```